# OpenMP slower than single threaded even though embarrassingly parallelizable

Tags: c, openmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


void func1(float *x, int n) {
    for (int ind=0; ind<n; ind++) {
        x[ind] = fabsf(x[ind]);
    }
}

void func2(float *x, int n) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int ind=0; ind<n; ind++) {
        x[ind] = fabsf(x[ind]);
    }
}


int main(void) {
    int TIMES = 10;
    int N = 1880000*128;
    float *arr = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

    float start_time1 = (float)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    for (int t=0; t<TIMES; t++) {
        func1(arr, N);
    }
    float duration1 = (float)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC - start_time1;

    float start_time2 = (float)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    for (int t=0; t<TIMES; t++) {
        func2(arr, N);
    }
    float duration2 = (float)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC - start_time2;

    free(arr);
    printf("duration1: %.4f\n", duration1 / TIMES);
    printf("duration2: %.4f\n", duration2 / TIMES);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with GCC (4.8.4) that came with Ubuntu 14.04:

```
> gcc -O3 -std=c99 -fopenmp -o test test.c -lm
> ./test
duration1: 0.1090
duration2: 0.3777
```

Why is `func2` slower? I am using the c4.2xlarge instance in AWS (8CPU, 16GB mem).

Comment: Get opposite [results here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/746872179149a142). Try running the code a few times.

Comment: Hmm, same results too. Any idea what is the reason?

Comment: I doubt that it makes a practical difference, but you should probably initialise the values of that array to avoid undefined behaviour. Also: Are you sure none of the outer loops gets optimised away?

Comment: Don't use `clock()` to time programs on Unix-like OS-es. Like, really, just don't. It only works on Windows.

Comment: @HristoIliev I've heard this a couple times, but what is the alternative? Edit: Nvm, `clock()` measures times spent in all threads, but `omp_get_wtime()` gives the correct wall time.